# Database design for international suppliers and their support language

Tags: database, database-design

I am new to the database world and want to design a database which contains many service providers. Some provide their services all over the world, some only for a few states. Also, I need to store the language in which they can support their customers.

I want to query efficiently:
1) All suppliers servicing a certain state.
2) All suppliers which support a certain language.

I thought of the following design:

- Country_Table {countryID : PK ...}
- State_Table   {stateID: PK, countryID : FK ...}
- Language_Table {languageID: PK, ....}
- Supplier_Table {supplierID : PK, supplierName, supplier address...}
- Supplier_Language_Table {supplierID : PK,FK , languageID : PK, FK}
- Supplier_State_Table { supplierID : PK, FK , stateID: PK, FK}

I have a few problems with this design:

1. What to do in case of a country that has no states (for instance: Egypt)? I thought of using countryID=0 for these cases. So in Country_Table, Texas is the state and USA is the country. However, Egypt is a state with countryID 0 . Is this a valid solution?
2. For each language the supplier supports I need to insert a row. Is it efficient for later querying suppliers by language or is there a better solution?
3. In Supplier_State_Table I need to insert a row for each state the supplier provides. This seems inefficient.  I thought of using stateID 0 to indicate the whole world. But even then, if supplier provides service to US only, having a data row for each US state seems crazy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No. Instead, have both a `Supplier_State_Table` and `Supplier_Country_Table`

2) This is fine.

3) Again, this is fine, databases are designed to handle a lot of data.